# dumping a MySQL table in chunks

Tags: mysql, database, backup, database-backups

I would like to backup one big innodb MySQL table, but unfortunately don't have enough free space to create a full dump of it. So I thought about dividing the backup to two parts. Meaning I will dump half of the table, move that file to an external backup location, and than backup the second half and move it also.

I'm used to doing: `mysqldump --user=$user --password=$pass --single-transaction --quick`

How can I perform such an operation one half at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can backup specifics tables like this

Tables t1, t2, and t3 from your DB.

```
mysqldump -u... -p... mydb t1 t2 t3 > mydb_tables.sql
```

Or you can create a mouting point (unix) or network drive (windows) and make your backup directly on it.

If you want to backup just a table in multiple part

```
mysqldump --databases X --tables Y --where="1 limit 1000000"
mysqldump --databases X --tables Y --where="myColumn < 1000"
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear, but I'm not looking to backup more than one table. I'm looking the backup one table in parts. One part, transfer, and then second part. I was thinking about doing the mount, but was told if something goes wrong during the backup the whole system might get stuck, so thought this solution might be safer.

Comment: Personally I will go for a mount, but I posted what you would like to do in my answer dump by query

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain the `1 limit 1000000`? I assume I understand the `myColumn < 1000` but not sure how the first is related / what it does. Also, do you have good reference that can lead me in mount creation (unix) ?

Comment: just google it, you can find plenty of website, tutorial and example very easily on the net.